# Wrong syntax when nesting 3 classes in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, nested-class

Would there be a  simple way to fix this error while keeping all 3 levels?

Deriving ClassA from object does not help.

Thanks in advance!

```
>>> class classA:
...     class classB(object):
...         def __init__(self):
...             self.b = 3
...         class classC(classA.classB):
...             def __init__(self):
...                 super(classC, self).__init__()
...                 self.c = 4
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in classA
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in classB
NameError: name 'classA' is not defined
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: class names will be shorter and code will be more readable

Comment: also, wanted to understand why thid=s does not work; maybe I miss some important concept

Comment: `classA.classB.classC` is no way shorter than `classC`...

Comment: @glglgl Maybe he saves one or another prefix with this.

Comment: @F.C. yes I also thought it should, but it does not; see the last line in the code sample, it is an error message

Comment: @ Markus: correct, except that I am not a 'he'

Comment: You might want to add that to your profile page, or choose change your username so people will notice, otherwise the assumption per default is "he" because it's most often correct, sadly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. At the time you define `classC`, `classA` does not exist yet.

It is only created after its body is fully executed. (The dict created from the body's execution is one parameter for the class creation call `class = type('classname', (superclass_1, superclass_2, superclass_3), said_dict})`.)

The easiest way would be defining them at the same level.

If absolutely needed, you can modify them later:

```
class classA:
    pass
class classB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 3
class classC(classB):
    def __init__(self):
        super(classC, self).__init__()
        self.c = 4
classA.classB = classB
classB.classC = classC
```

Comment: It might be useful to add to your answer an explanation of why classA cannot exist until all of the statements in the class body have been executed.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
class classA:
    pass

class classB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 3
classA.classB = classB

class classC(classA.classB):
    def __init__(self):
        super(classC, self).__init__()
        self.c = 4

classA.classB.classC = classC
```

Comment: Apart from makeing the last line more verbose, this doesn't add anything to @glglgl's answer.

Comment: @Duncan, you are right but when I posted it glglgl's answer didn't have the code